# Energies of a 3-jet event

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, gluons

A 3-jet event can arise when a quark and an anti-quark are pair produced and, subsequently, one of these particles produces a gluon via bremsstrahlung.

On top of page 270 of "Particle Physics in the LHC Era", it is stated that the gluon jet usually has the lowest energy.  Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The whole jet analysis is a subject of its own, [see this](http://jets.physics.harvard.edu/) for example .

The hand waving answer is that gluons appear as a type of strong bremsstrahlung, and pick up only some of the energy of the primary quark, incrementally.

In this [entry](http://jets.physics.harvard.edu/qvg/)  where  they calculate with a program the theoretical spectra of quarkand gluon jets, the difference is obvious. In data this would show as extra peaks in what seems to be radial- momentum, that could be separated with a fit.

Comment: You mentioned that the gluons "pick up only some of the energy of the primary quark, incrementally."  Why can't it pick up a lot of energy from the primary quark?

Comment: Because of the mathematics, as it is with the electromagnetic analogous, the Brehmsstrahlun radiation. It is all a matter of wavefunctions and consequent probabilities that they have put in the models I have linked.

Comment: Is there a physical explanation of why bremsstrahlung can't pick up a lot of energy?

Comment: it is all in the mathematics that fits the observations maybe this will help http://www.astro.utu.fi/~cflynn/astroII/l3.html

Comment: The "physical explnation"  I can see is that the enegy to the brem photon is given by the dp/dt of the acceeration, and it would be a strange  experimental situation where the addition of a dp/dt would be larger than the original electron momentum..